# Play App does not execute scheduled Task on heroku

Tags: java, heroku, playframework, akka

My Play App schedules a daily Task using Akka like this:

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

private void schedule() {
    try {
        Time.CronExpression e = new Time.CronExpression("0 0 0 ? * *");
        Date nextValidTimeAfter = e.getNextValidTimeAfter(new Date());
        FiniteDuration d = Duration.create(
                nextValidTimeAfter.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis(),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        Logger.debug("Scheduling to run at "+nextValidTimeAfter);

        scheduler = Akka.system().scheduler().scheduleOnce(d, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Logger.debug("Running scheduler");
                //do something
                schedule(); //Schedule for next time
            }
        }, Akka.system().dispatcher());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.error("", e);
    }
}
}
```

The Task executes on localhost as expected. However, it does not get executed on heroku though it logs `Scheduling to run at ...`

Comment: Heroku apps are shut down when app uses only one dyno and receives no traffic in an hour. Are you sure your app is still running when the scheduled task is supposed to be run?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities: either Heroku is sleeping your app due to inactivity ([this happens for free apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dyno-sleeping)), or it is restarting your dyno before the job runs (as it will every 24 hours).

It would be better to use the [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) to schedule the task. This is also more scalable since you probably don't want to run this job on every instance of your app.